# Regex to pass only with certain characters across entire string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string (could be any length, up to 255 characters) which will need to check every single character and ensure it only contains the following characters (could be in any order):

- letters (a-z case insensitive so also A-Z)
- numbers (0-9)
- hyphen (-)
- ampersand (&)
- apostrophe (‘)
- full stop (.)
- slash (/)
- single space only (ideally it would be nice if this could be flagged separately to allow me to remove any additional unwanted whitespace)

So for example, the following would succeed

> 10 Downing Street

but the following would not

> 10, Downing Street

Is regex able to do this? Will be using PHP `preg_match` function.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What pattern did you come up with so far?

Comment: yes possible :) you can try something and then people will help you

Comment: Sure my regex is absolutely crap - I've got upto this: /([a-zA-Z0-9])/ but it only checks the first character - sorry about my stupidness :( any starter with explaination would be useful, wont need the entire solution if it takes alot of time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single character matches can be done with a character class, similar to what you have attempted:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-&'./]
```

You would then specify that there can be any number greater than or equal to one of these characters by adding `+` after it. But since you want to validate that is should be no longer than 255 characters, you can do this as well with an explicit quantifier: `{0,255}` allows any length from zero to 255. Note that the hyphen is escaped, because it has a special meaning within a character class. You can make this a little simpler by using the `i` modifier to make the pattern case-insensitive.

The requirement of matching a single space is a *little* more complex, there are a couple of ways this could be done but since you also say you want to normalise these to a single space, I suggest you do this first so that you can just add space to your character class for simplicity. This can easily be done with another regex:

```
/ +/
```

This matches every block of 1 or more space characters, so you then simply replace all matches with a single space.

Now that you know the string only contains single spaces, you can simply assert that the entire string contains only characters in your list by using the `^` and `$` start- and end-of subject assertions. So putting it all together, you get something like this:

```
// Replace all space blocks to a single space
$normalizedSpace = preg_replace('# +#', ' ', $input);

// Validate the input contains only the chars you want
if (!preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\-&\'./ ]{0,255}$#i', $normalizedSpace)) {
    // Data invalid, handle error here
} else {
    // If you get here the data is valid
    $validData = trim($normalizedSpace);
}
```

I suspect you will also want to `trim()` the data as well, although this may not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

This will match the allowed characters, allowing up to 255 characters (or an empty string).

```
/^[a-z0-9'.\/& -]{0,255}$/iD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can negate a regex range:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 -'&./]
```

This will match any character BUT a-z,A-Z,0-9,' ','-', ''&, '.', '/'.

If you get a match there is an error in your string.

This does npot handle the whitspace because this is an problem you should deal with BEFORE validating the string.

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?230179-How-do-I-reduce-multiple-spaces-into-a-single-space-using-preg_replace